# Persistent `upsert` isn't working

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am apparently confused about Persistent's `upsert` function and how it works with Postgres 9.5.

I am writing a Yesod app that takes in a JSON value, parses it, and then does an `upsert` on the appropriate database table.  I have verified that the JSON gets parsed into a valid value.  See the code:

```
postITSClientsR :: Handler TypedContent
postITSClientsR = do
  i <- requireJsonBody :: Handler IntensiveTreatmentClient
  row <- runDB $ upsert i []
  selectRep . provideJson $ row
```

I have also verified that this model type has a Uniqueness constraint:

```
IntensiveTreatmentClient json
  clientId ClientId
  UniqueIntensiveTreatmentClientClientId clientId
  etc...
```

However, my new value isn't getting saved.  I have verified this a few times, but the Yesod log is probably the most telling, since it reports:

```
POST /api/itsClients
  Params: [("{\"clientId\":1,...","")]
  Request Body: {"clientId":1,...}
  Accept: */*
  Status: 200 OK 0.005041s
```

(Fields have been purposefully removed to anonymize)  Typically, the log would report the SQL query that got run, and this isn't reporting any.

What is going on?  Yesod or Persistent are just silently dropping my query with no error.

Comment: This is actually not an `upsert`, but a `repsert` I think.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am not sure what you mean.  The `upsert` documentation says that an `upsert` with an empty list passed in the second argument (as in `upsert val []`) is equivalent to a `repsert` that uses the Uniqueness constraint as a key.

Comment: anyway, it is perhaps a good idea to look for the log of the *response body*. We only see the request here. It is possible that for example the query goes wrong, but we do not see that.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Good suggestion.  The response body does not reflect the changes I'm trying to save.

Answer (score 0):

I think upsert comment is bug.
I opened pull request [added: PersistentTest: upsert fail, it expected equivalent repsert by ncaq · Pull Request #821 · yesodweb/persistent](https://github.com/yesodweb/persistent/pull/821)

upsert do not update when two argument list is empty.

If you want unique of repsert.
This code created by me, you can use with stack overflow cc license.

```hs
-- | if a record exist by unique, then 'replace', else 'insert'
repsertBy :: ( PersistEntityBackend record ~ BaseBackend backend
             , PersistStoreWrite backend
             , PersistEntity record
             , PersistUniqueRead backend
             , MonadIO m) =>
             record -> ReaderT backend m (Key record)
repsertBy record = do
    me <- getByValue record
    case me of
        Nothing             -> insert record
        Just (Entity key _) -> replace key record >> return key
```

But, this code rejected at Yesod mainstream.
Because, when multiple unique constants exist then undefined.